# Unmarshal XML from XSD failed with JAR Execution with "java.io.IOException: Buffer already closed"

Tags: java, xml, xsd, unmarshalling

I have a java code that extract an Xml section from a PDF (Apache PDFBox) and unmarshall it to a java Class.

On local execution with IntelliJ, all is OK, but when I deploy jar on an openshift cluster, unmarshal is ko with "java.io.IOException: Buffer already closed"

From my PDF, I extract a List

Then, I create an unmarshal like this :

```
try {
      JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(typeClasse.getClass());
      Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();
      SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
      String xsdFilePath = getXSD();
      Schema schema = factory.newSchema(this.getClass().getResource("/" + xsdFilePath));
      unmarshaller.setSchema(schema);
      unmarshaller.setEventHandler(event -> false);
      return unmarshaller;
    } catch (JAXBException | SAXException e) {
      throw new UnmarshallException(e);
    }
```

typeClasse is my output unmarshall class, getXSD() give me the path on my root XSD definition, all my XSD are on the same directory "xsd" on resource java folder and the one return by getXSD() include all the other. Path is like "xsd/myparentXSD.xsd"

Then, with my List (myList) I do this code that return a List where T is the typeClasse.

```
myList.stream()
        .map(myObject -> unmarshallFichier(myObject, unmarshaller))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

unmarshaller is the one detail below and unmarshallFichier is :

```
try {
  StreamSource stream = new StreamSource(myObject);
  JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(stream, typeClasse.getClass());
  return (T) jaxbElement.getValue();
} catch (JAXBException e) {
  throw new UnmarshallException(e);
}
```

But on openshift, this code is wrong and produce java.io.IOException: Buffer already closed (but not  inc local)

What is wrong whith this ?

Comment: It might not be openshift problem, but rather how your docker image looks like.  Try to run it from inside docker, for example docker run -it yourimage sh. and then inside the terminal run your java class and actually look at the folder that has your XSDs

Comment: I have extract jar file that is deploy on openshift and XSD are correctly in myJar.jar\BOOT-INF\classes\xsd\ folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
StreamSource stream = new StreamSource(myObject);
```

What is `myObject` in this instance? Is it a [InputStream](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/io/InputStream.html) or a [Reader](https://docs.oracle.com/javase%2F7%2Fdocs%2Fapi%2F%2F/java/io/Reader.html)?

Judging by the exception I get the feeling you are trying to read from a `Reader` or `InputStream` more than once.

**Please note that you can only read from an `InputStream` / `Reader` once.**

Perhaps you want to do something like the following so you create a new `InputStream` each time you iterate the list?

```java
public interface InputStreamSource {
   InputStream get() throws IOException;
}

public class MyClass {
   // myList is a long-lived object and can be iterated multiple times
   // since we create a new InputStream each time we call InputStreamSource.get() 
   private final List<InputStreamSource> myList = List.of(
      () -> new FileInputStream("path/to/file1.xml"),
      () -> new FileInputStream("path/to/file2.xml")
   );

   public List<Object> doIt() {
      return myList.stream()
         .map(myObject -> unmarshallFichier(myObject, unmarshaller))
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
   }

   private Object unmarshallFichier(InputStreamSource streamSource, Unmarshaller unmarshaller) {
      try (InputStream in = streamSource.get()) {
         StreamSource stream = new StreamSource(in);
         JAXBElement<?> jaxbElement = unmarshaller.unmarshal(stream, typeClasse.getClass());
         return (T) jaxbElement.getValue();
      } catch (JAXBException e) {
         throw new UnmarshallException(e);
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: myObject is an InputStream. But why local execution is OK and jar execution ons erver is KO ?

Comment: Why did you use a List<InputStreamSource> ? My XML is in a  List<InputStream>

Comment: `List<InputStream>` is a problem if you want to iterate the list more than once. Each `InputStream` can only be read from once. After you have read from an `InputStream` it should be discarded since it's useless at that point

Comment: Ok but I have juste on InputStream to read, not many. myObject  have to contain only one xml to unmarshal. I don't understand where my Inpustream is read twice ....

Comment: Perhaps when you run in intellij you are only reading from the `InputStream` once. But on openshift the process is running for longer and the code is executing a second/third time on the same `InputStream` instance?

Comment: Also, make sure you `close()` your `InputStream` after use. I prefer to use a [try with resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block (see my example)

Comment: I thinks it's OK. I have move the unmarshallFichier method into the try that create the InputStream from the PDF .... And it's OK. It's always obscur for me but OK !! Thanks to you.